# How old was this woman (from Tomb of Annihilation) at her death?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, lore, tomb-of-annihilation

How is it possible?

[Page 92 of the ToA adventure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/dwellers-of-the-forbidden-city#FallofOmu) says:

> A little over a century ago, Acererak entered Omu and slew all nine trickster gods. He then enslaved the Omuans and forced them to carve out a tomb for their defeated gods. When the tomb was complete, Acererak murdered the Omuans and sealed them in the tomb with their false gods.

So, group A was killed at moment 1. Okay.

> group A = Omuans;
>  moment 1 = *a little over a century ago*

Later in the adventure, [it says on p. 165](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/tomb-of-the-nine-gods#53CryptoftheSunQueen):

> After Acererak slew the trickster gods of Omu and enslaved the city, Napaka, the city’s elderly queen, chose not to flee, and instead offered herself as a sacrifice in exchange for the release of her people.

So, person B was killed at the same time. Okay.

> person B = Napaka;
>  same time = *a little over a century ago*

[Page 69 of the adventure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/the-land-of-chult#KirSabal) says:

> Seventeen-year-old Princess Mwaxanaré  is the oldest living descendant of the royal families of Omu and the primary heir to the fallen kingdom. She and her six-year-old brother Na [...]

So person C was born at moment 2. Okay.

> person C = Na;
>  moment 2 = 6 years ago

The same page continues:

> Their great-grandmother, Napaka, was the last ruling queen of Omu; their father, Omek, died in a fall, and their mother, Razaan, was killed by pterafolk.

Hm, it looks like his mother (person D) was able to bear children at moment 2. Also, she is a granddaughter of person B. But person B was killed at moment 1.

> person B = Napaka;
>  person D = Razaan;
>  moment 1 = *a little over a century ago*;
>  moment 2 = 6 years ago

[According to page 137](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/tomb-of-the-nine-gods#NepartaksSkull):

> The skull in the crystal box belongs to Nepartak, the 10-year-old granddaughter of Napaka, the last queen of Omu.

So, another granddaughter of person B was born at the time of moment 3. That is strange.

> person B = Napaka;
>  moment 3 = 110 years ago

How old was person D when she bore her son? 104? Really?

How old was she when she died? Between 104 and 110?

Is this natural for Chultans?

> person D = Razaan

Comment: your last 3 points don't make any sense. moments 1 and 2 are "years ago", moment 3 is just a period of time? Why do you think Person D is over 100 when her son is born? What does a skull belonging to a 10 year old girl have to do with anything?

Comment: @GreySage Their logic might not be clear, but their question is (how old was Person D when they died.) If anything, asking about the average age of Chultans may be separate, but it may be best for OP to simply ask how old that person is and submit their logic as an answer (with opportunity to be disputed/clarified) by other answers.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is natrual for chultans to bear children at that age or are you asking if you have correctly assumed the age of person D at the moment that they gave birth to their son?

Comment: @NautArch I think the answers sufficiently show my concern was misplaced. Comment removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## We don't know how old Person D was; but she very plausibly could have been about 49-55 years old

It seems like you've misunderstood—or incorrectly extrapolated—the relationships between each of these characters, so I'm going to try to summarize everything all at once to make things a bit clearer.

- Person B, Great-Grandmother of Person C, died ~100 years ago at an age that can be described as "Elderly".
- Person C, Six years old at the time the adventure takes place.
- Person D, mother of Person C, and Granddaughter of Person B, age unknown
- Person E (not given an ID in original post), Parent of Person D and direct offspring of Person B

So let's assume, for the sake of argument, Person B had a daughter or son (Person E) who was about 10 years old at the time they died. In about 45 years (at 55 years old) they beget Person D, and then Person D gives birth about (55-6) 49 years later to their youngest son. In terms of normal human fertility ranges, that's pretty unusual, but certainly plausible, especially if Person E were male.

Comment: So what is correct? I am a little bit confused with all these things.

Comment: @Ohar The post as-written is correct, to the best of my knowledge. My comment was in reference to a now-deleted section of this answer that delved into examining the age of a different character, based on a misunderstanding I had about their presence in the story.

Answer (score 13):

## It's impossible to know her exact age, but probably not older than 40-50

Here is my understanding of the described events:

> Napaka died in the event about 100 years ago. An unnamed child escaped. That child eventually had a daughter Razaan and a daughter Nepartak (the skull) (EDIT: this could potentially be Razaan's cousin via an aunt or uncle, since we dont know much about Nepartak). Razan later had a daughter and son, Mwaxanaré and Na.

It's easy to miss (I missed it initially, too), but the quote on page 69 labels Person B as the **Great** Grandmother of the two, not the Grandmother.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94227/discussion-on-answer-by-sir-cinnamon-how-old-was-this-woman-from-tomb-of-annihi).